# Can I get gcp compute recommendations to resize the instance using any stackdriver monitoring api or gcloud command

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, gcloud, libcloud

I want to get the recommendation to resize the instances which gcp shows on there ui for compute instances either through any gcloud command or any api which google provides for stackdriver. (any method would work, just need to get the data of there recommendations they provide of resizing the instances)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google has made this available through its [Recommender API](https://cloud.google.com/recommender/docs/overview) (note that it still in beta).

You can interact with it with eitherthe gcloud command-line tool, for example, to list recommendations on Compute Engine instance type:

```
gcloud beta recommender recommendations list \
    --project=example-project \
    --location=us-central1-a \
    --recommender=google.compute.instance.MachineTypeRecommender \
    --format=json
```

or with the REST API. For example:

```
curl \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-access-token)"  \
    -H "x-goog-user-project: example-project" \
    "https://recommender.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/example-project/locations/us-central1-a/recommenders/google.compute.instance.MachineTypeRecommender/recommendations"
```

You can have a look [here](https://cloud.google.com/recommender/docs/using-api) to get more details info about available actions.